# Change search results order for Admin -> Appearance -> Menus -> Pages -> View all

Tags: menus, wp-admin, pagination

I have over 200+ pages (about 100 for each of my two languages).

How I can change the order of results? I need the same as on the page with Page list.
On the Page list e.g. you have a parent page and 300 child pages for it. It means that you will see child pages over paginations without interruption of another parent page and its children. It's difficult to explain. But here what we see in the standard Page list (and it is good for me):
[image]
Parent page A

- child A1
- child A2
  ...
- child A300

Ande then

Parent page B

- child B1
- child B2
  ...
- child B300

But on `Admin -> Appearance -> Menus -> Pages -> View all` now I have pagination of four pages.
And if e.g on page #2 begin Parent A and then it children, it can be suddenly interrupted by Parent B. Then you can again see Parent A and its children on the next page (#3).
[image]

Again. I need the list of parents and their child not to be interrupted by each other. Parent B list should not interrupt Parent A.

**UPD**: I think I'm looking for hook something like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/293397/202074)

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Our focus here is WordPress programming. If this is a plugin or theme that you're developing, please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/383552/edit) to include any relevant code. If this isn't a programming question, you should probably ask elsewhere — perhaps the official WordPress Support forums.

Comment: @PatJ hi! It is standard WP behavior. In an answer to my question, I expect some function with a hook or something like this to change the standard behavior of the View all responses.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest [editing the question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/383552/edit) to make it clear you're looking for a hook or a filter, since the question currently reads like you're looking for help using WordPress generally.

Comment: I'm looking for a hook. Updated my question with the link on a similar hook example.